# If $S=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{3}{8}+...$ what is the closest integer to $e^S$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

If $S=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{3}{8}+...$ what is the closest integer to $e^S$
I thought that this series could be represented as $\ln{2}$ but it is $\ln{4}$ somehow? Any suggestions please send.

Comment: Try to write the series (with finite number of terms) on the form $(1+1/2+ \ldots + 1/N) - (1 + 1/2 + \ldots + 1/M)$. Its the difference between two harmonic series and using the asymptotics of the harmonic series you can find its sum.

Comment: Rearranging terms is only something you can do for absolutely convergent series and I am not sure this series is absolutely convergent. Is it the denominators that are multiples of 4 that are being altered in $S$ as compared to the harmonic series?

Comment: To be clear, it's the harmonic series, except that when the denominator is a multiple of $4$, the numerator is $-3$ instead of $1$?

Comment: @LaarsHelenius That is not an issue here and one does not need to do any scary rearrangements to get the result. You simple look at the first $n$ terms as you normally would and rearrange them to more easily see a pattern (and you can rearrange a finite series as much as you want). The problem with rearrangements you are thinking about comes about when you freely choose the first $n$ terms among *all* terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from @vonbrand's answer,
$$\begin{align*}
   S_n
     &= H_n - H_{\lfloor n / 4 \rfloor} \implies e^{S_n}=\exp\left( H_n - H_{\lfloor n / 4 \rfloor}  \right)=\frac {\exp\left( H_n\right)}{\exp\left(H_{\lfloor n / 4 \rfloor}\right) }
\end{align*}$$ Using the asymptotics of harmonic numbers, an approximation is
$$e^{S_n}\sim\frac{n+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{24 n}-\frac{1}{48 n^2} }{m+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{24 m}-\frac{1}{48 m^2}}\qquad \text{where} \qquad m=\lfloor n / 4 \rfloor$$
Disregarding the floors, this would give for large values of $n$
$$e^{S_n}=4-\frac{6}{n}+\frac{19}{2 n^2}-\frac{39}{4
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

If your sum is really (there are certainly lots of other ways to go on!):

$\begin{align*}
   S_n
     &= 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}
          + \left(\frac{1}{4} - 1\right) + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7}
          + \left(\frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{2}\right) + \dotsm
          + \left(\frac{1}{12} - \frac{1}{3}\right) + \dotsm \\
     &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \frac{1}{k}
           - \sum_{1 \le k \le \lfloor n / 4 \rfloor}  \frac{1}{k}
\end{align*}$

In terms of harmonic numbers:

$\begin{align*}
   H_n
     &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \frac{1}{k}
\end{align*}$

your sum is just:

$\begin{align*}
   S_n
     &= H_n - H_{\lfloor n / 4 \rfloor}
\end{align*}$

then, as hinted in comments, you can use the (rather crude) bound on the harmonic numbers $\ln n \le H_n \le \ln n + 1$:

$\begin{align*}
   \ln n - (\ln \lfloor n / 4 \rfloor + 1)
      &\le S_n
       \le \ln n + 1 - \ln \lfloor n / 4 \rfloor
\end{align*}$

This tells you that, disregarding the floors, we have approximately:

$\begin{align*}
  \ln 4 - 1
    &\le S_n
     \le \ln 4 + 1
\end{align*}$

Thus $e^{S_n}$ is between $4 / e = 1.4715$ and $4 e = 10.873$. Better bounds on $H_n$ give sharper values.